# Cannot connect to my MongoDB using Compass tool after upgrading from 1.25 to 1.30

Tags: database, mongodb, connection-string, compass

I get the below error message when I use a used-to-be working connection string to connect to my Mongo DB on the server.
This started happening after I upgraded my Compass from 1.25 v to 1.30 v.
I had to upgrade because the export collection feature was not exporting all the fields from the document

Error message:

```
Server at localhost:27017 reports maximum wire version 5, but this
version of the Node.js Driver requires at least 6 (MongoDB 3.6)
```

Please help as I use this to generate reports to check the app usage and various other user activity reports

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by downgrading to version 1.29.5:

https://github.com/mongodb-js/compass/releases/tag/v1.29.5

Also, disable automatic updates by going to Help -> Privacy Settings to avoid this happening again.

It seems that there is a breaking change starting at MongoDB Compass v1.29.6.

https://github.com/mongodb-js/compass/releases/tag/v1.29.6

There's this line:

> dependencies: bump driver to 4.2.1, mongosh to 1.1.6

My guess is that going from mongodb driver 4.1.0 to 4.2.1 had a breaking change - might be related to this:

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/compare/v4.1.0...v4.2.1#diff-648afe3d986261d8f2015b2b131b0e4a448d4dc6946cfde1a7a836876cee255eR24

Comment: Downgrading works, but the application auto updates even when that option is disabled. Very annoying.

Comment: As a consequence, you need `mongosh 1.1.5` when connecting to a database when connecting with the latest `mongosh`-version shows the same error.